# Is there's any way to get this file upload section to the right side like other text boxes

Tags: html, css

i want to get this file upload button to the right side like other text boxes.
tried editing the CSS file seems not working.
I'll put the CSS code and HTML code below.
if I can add something like add your image like drag and drop option that'll be very cool :)
little left algin the file upload area

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="PostYourAD.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.asp">Post Your AD</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
      </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logo" align = "left" width="150" height="150" />
        </div>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <h1 align = "center">Post Your AD</h1>
    <br><br>
      
        <div class="container">
            <form action="/action_page.php">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-25">
                <label for="images">Upload Your Images</label>
                <div class="col-75">
                <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
             </div>
             </div>
             </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-25">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-75">
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name..">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-25">
                  <label for="location">Location</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-75">
                  <input type="text" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Your Location..">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-25">
                  <label for="price">Price</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-75">
                  <input type="text" id="price" name="price" placeholder="Enter the Price..">
                </div>
              </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-25">
                <label for="pnumber">Phone Number</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-75">
                <input type="text" id="pnumber" name="pnumber" placeholder="Your Phone Number..">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-25">
                <label for="Type">Type</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-75">
                <select id="type" name="type">
                    <option value="type">Select a Type</option>
                    <option value="land">Land</option>
                    <option value="vehicale">Vehicale</option> 
                    <option value="house">House</option>
                    <option value="annex">Annex</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-25">
                <label for="description">Description</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-75">
                <textarea id="description" name="description" placeholder="Write Your Description.." style="height:200px"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
              <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
            </form>
          </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=text], select, textarea {
 text-align: justify;
    vertical-align:super;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  resize: vertical;
}
input[type=file] {
    text-align: justify;
       vertical-align:super;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 12px;
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     border-radius: 4px;
     resize: vertical;
   }

label {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: middle;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
}

.col-25 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.col-75 {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .col-25, .col-75, input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
    li {
    float: right;
  }
  
  a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like one of the closings tags in your file input code is misplaced:

You have this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-25">
    <label for="images">Upload Your Images</label>
  <div class="col-75">
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should have this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-25">
    <label for="images">Upload Your Images</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-75">
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
  </div>
</div>
```

Reading you HTML code, you're closing the "html" tag, but the opening one, which should be below the doctype, is missing.

If I may, I don't know if it's the copy / paste who misaligned your tags, but I advise you to always align your tags correctly, or use a formatter. It will help you to edit your code and to spot small errors like this one more easily ;)

Answer (score 0):

You placed the `</div>` for an element of the class `col-75` wrongly. Here's the corrected version: https://jsfiddle.net/fw26y5pe/.